# Getting a specific number of results from a table

Tags: sql

I'm  new to mySQLi / SQL in general, so I wanted to ask a question regarding retrieving a certain amount of results in a specific way. Basically what I want to do is get all available information about the three fastest ships in the table below (using maxWarp field), but I don't know how to quite write that in SQL. I don't think it would just be right to say "`SELECT * FROM Fleet WHERE maxWarp > 6`"

```
**Table name: Fleet**
name         class           crew    maxWarp
Enterprise   Constitution    430     8
Excalibur    Ambassador      260     9
Farragut     Constitution    420     9
Prokofiev    Andromeda       100     6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select * from fleet order by maxwrap desc limit 3;